# Сделать ссылку из строки php

Tags: php

Есть строка

```
Текст текст текст № 32456
```

Можно число сделать ссылкой ?

Comment: можно, воспользуйтесь регулярным выражением и функцией `preg_replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать регулярные выражения

```
$txt = "Текст текст текст № 32456";

$result = preg_replace("/№\s*(\d+)/", '№ <a href="#$1">$1</a>', $txt);
```

где `$1` в подстановке, это ссылка на найденную группу соответствия.

результат:

```
Текст текст текст № <a href="#32456">32456</a>
```